# SSH hosts.deny and hosts.allow

Tags: ssh, iptables, root

I have this content in `hosts.deny` (with a new line at the end):

```
#
# hosts.deny    This file describes the names of the hosts which are
#       *not* allowed to use the local INET services, as decided
#       by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' server.
#
# The portmap line is redundant, but it is left to remind you that
# the new secure portmap uses hosts.deny and hosts.allow.  In particular
# you should know that NFS uses portmap!

sshd : ALL
```

And this in `hosts.allow`:

```
#
# hosts.allow   This file describes the names of the hosts which are
#       allowed to use the local INET services, as decided
#       by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' server.
#

sshd: our.ip.add.ress: allow
```

Then, we executed this piece of code to restart SSH:

`/etc/init.d/sshd restart`

And again, here is a new line at the end. But, we can still reach the SSH service from another server and attempt to login. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Are you really using `hosts.accept` or is that a typo?

Comment: Typo, thnx, I meant `allow` indeed ;).

Comment: Are you *able* to login?You should get a message ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: I can suggest the output of James O'Gorman. It will work

Answer (score 3):

Your /etc/hosts.deny, I think you have a syntax error.  There shouldn't be be a space between "sshd" and the colon.  So, it should read:

```
sshd: ALL
```

On the "allow" side, I have lines like:

```
sshd: 192.168.1.1
```

There's no trailing text after the IP address.

Comment: I thought this at first, but the `hosts_access(5)` man page gives an example of `daemon_list : client_list [ : shell_command ]`.

Comment: Hmm.  Yes, I see that.  Interestingly, when they give actual examples, they don't have the space between the daemon and the colon.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `: allow` in `hosts.allow`. It should just look like this:

```
sshd: 192.168.2.200
```

If you have console access you can try blocking everything that uses tcpwrappers in case it's an issue with the service name:

`hosts.deny`:

```
ALL: ALL
```

`hosts.allow`:

```
ALL: 192.168.2.200
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it worth checking to see that support for tcp-wrappers was actually compiled into the sshd you're using?

It needs to have been compiled with either of the --with-libwrap or --with-tcp-wrappers options, according the o'reilly snail book.

(I'm not certain if most distros enable this by default, or what the default compile time option is for open ssh).

I checked mine just now by doing:

```
ldd /usr/sbin/sshd | egrep 'wrap'
```

which indicated

```
libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00002ba50fa9c000)
```

(h/t to [this Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15622/output-compiler-options-from-ssh))

Comment: For what it helps, as of openssh 6.7 support for  tcpwrappers/libwrap has been removed.