# ssh tunnel error "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to use an ssh tunnel from my office machine to my home machine, and get an error when I try to use it.

What I'm doing is starting one shell like so:

```
ssh -gL 12345:my.home.domain:22 my.home.domain
```

This is giving me a proper shell, no problem.  What I normally do then is ssh to my home machine through this office machine, like so:

```
ssh -p 12345 127.0.0.1
```

This has always worked for me, until last week, when I set up a new system on my home machine (switching from Ubuntu to Debian).  Now I get an error.  I can still open up my initial ssh connection, but when I try to use that tunnel, I get (on the office machine) this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Also, when that happens, the open shell that I have the tunnelling set up through gets this line spat out at it:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

At which point, I'm at a loss.  If any more info is needed, I'll be happy to post it.

============= further to that ==============

After fiddling around further, I've found that I'm getting a different response from the server (my home machine that is) when I try to telnet in on the various ports.  If I try:

```
telnet my.home.domain 22
```

I get this back:

```
Trying <my ip address>...
Connected to <my domain>.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2
```

Which is what I would expect.  After setting up the tunnel though, and then telnetting to that, I see this response:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

============== and further still ==================

As per [kbulgrien](https://serverfault.com/users/101931/kbulgrien)'s suggestion, here is the output from the client machine with the -v option:

```
ssh -vp 24600 127.0.0.1
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 24600.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/jacob/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jacob/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jacob/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jacob/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jacob/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jacob/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: One cause of the `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` error relates to the connecting host being listed in the `/etc/hosts.deny`.

Comment: Hm - if I cat /ets/hosts.deny on that machine, every line is remarked.

Comment: May I suggest adding `-v` to the ssh command that fails?  Does the ensuing output give any other indication of failure (i.e. `channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`).

Comment: Sorry, it just occured to me that it is helpful to have `-v` on both the tunnel and failing ssh commands (looking for something more than `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out`).  It might be noteworthy to mention that one can add multiple `-v` (up to three) to increase verbosity.  I wouldn't necessarily post the whole spew, but it might be worth perusing for words that seem to indicate a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you have more then ssh 10 sessions waiting for insert the password, you have that kind of error, i remember that was recent ssh bug, if you would verify this, use the command below

```
for i in {1..15};do ssh -fNt pippo@remote.server.com & >/dev/null ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened on a recent install.  In this situation /etc/hosts.deny existed and had no settings that explicity denied access, so the circumstances seem similar.  It was necessary to alter /etc/hosts.allow to add something like:

```
sshd: 192.168.127.0/255.255.255.128
```

The IP details need to be adjusted to your needs, or are replaced with `ALL` if there is no concern with allowing ssh from everywhere.

After making the changes, stop and restart sshd.

Upvoted answers to following question provide more examples.

[SSH hosts.deny and hosts.allow](https://serverfault.com/questions/345558/ssh-hosts-deny-and-hosts-allow)

Here is someone else's testimony that links the error message with the solution.

[How To Fix : ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host problem when logging in with SSH](http://www.netdip.com/how-to-fix-ssh_exchange_identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-problem-when-logging-in-with-ssh-1rp/)

Comment: Hmm - sadly that didn't fix it for me.  I think my situation differs from the ones in the example.  I am able to ssh in on port 22 with no trouble.  It's only when I try to tunnel through another port that I get the errors mentioned.

Comment: Granted that the tunnel is a distinctive difference. Given that, does this help: https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-97951.html ? I have also found references to an indication that uninstalling and re-installing the sshd package on debian-like systems corrects an issue with keys that causes the behavior you describe ( https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-97951.html et. al. ).

Comment: You do have sshd (openssh-server) installed on both systems, right?

Comment: Yupyup.  I've been doing this for quite a long time, and only ran into trouble last week after switching to Debian on my home machine (the server).  I'll try your suggestion of un/re-installing sshd when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in the end solved the problem by correcting the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
```

or

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

without that config I never get reverse connection to my ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to insert to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the gateway machine the following lines:

```
Match User <username>
   GatewayPorts yes
```

See more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/50075)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my Linux, Salix 14.0 (Slackware 14.0), the solution was easy.

The problem was the script /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd, has not permission for execution.

Just `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd` for run this scrpit at boot.

This script execute sshd->
/usr/local/sbin/sshd (SSH Daemon)